# SQL Server 2008 for Small Business on windows 7 Pro

Tags: sql-server, windows-7

I'm beyond confused with **SQL Server 2008 R2 for Small Business**. I have tried installing on **SBS 2008**, it requires another server with a domain.

Now I'm trying on **Windows 7 Professional** and it says this OS is not supported for this edition yet it clearly says it is supported on the back of the SQL Server 2008 for Small Business box.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if you fit all the requirements for installing SQL Server 2008 R2 for Small Business on Windows 7 Pro ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You **must** install SQL server either on the primary server (bad idea) or on a second server with the second Win server license coming with SBS premium. Installing it on anything else is a violation of the license. This has no technical reasons at all and is just part of MS' usual bizarre licensing schemes.

Without knowing the text on the box, my guess us that it refers to the compability of Win7 as a client.